# Can't import Android library

Tags: android, jcenter

I'm trying to use RecyclerView Helper, but can't get project work with it. 
Here is the library that I'm trying to use: https://github.com/nisrulz/recyclerviewhelper

But getting this error:

```
   Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:{latest version}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
    Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        def supportLibVersion="{latest version}"
// Required
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
        implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

// RecyclerViewHelper
        implementation "com.github.nisrulz:recyclerviewhelper:${supportLibVersion}"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the project.gradle file ,you import library in wrong gradle file.please import this library on app.gradle file.

Import this on app.gradle

```
dependencies {



implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.github.nisrulz:recyclerviewhelper:27.1.1'

}
```

Import this on project.gradle

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `latest version` is a placeholder text. The `latest version` should be replaced with the latest version of SDK you need.

Please use this

```
def supportLibVersion="27.1.1"
```

instead of

```
def supportLibVersion="{latest version}"
```

Your library documentation also have this line

> where `{latest version}` corresponds to published version in `27.1.1`.